# Authlogic performance? - Any request with SELECT *

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

I have a little performance issue with Authlogic - I dealed with them over days... and i can't figure out!

The Problem is: I use the standard-Authlogic installation with following code in the application_controler to get the current_user (and to persits the session):

```
def current_user_session
  return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
  @current_user_session = UserSession.find
end
def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
  @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
end
```

Now the performance issue: Authlogic generates on ever request to the site a SQL-statement to persist the session and gets back the current_user. But the SQL Statement is like:

```
**User Load (0.3ms)** SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = '1') LIMIT 1
```

this `SELECT *` is my problem!
1. I don't want a current_user, that has all the attributes from the User-Model (there are a lot of stuff which I don't use by every request - for example hobbies or prefered_music etc. (a lot of data))
2. A SELECT * is slower than a SELECT a,b,c...

I want something like:

```
**User Load (0.1ms)** SELECT id, name, profilphoto_file_name FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = '1') LIMIT 1
```

But `UserSession.find(:select => "id,...")` didn't work because `.find` is a method from Authlogic (session/persistence.rb line 36) and not from ActiveRecord!

Now I don't know where Authlogic forms the SQL-Statement???

(my second idea is: split the User-Model into: user and user_details - so the SELECT * From users is not soo underperformant, but I would prefer the Authlogic hack.)

Thanks you!

Comment: I wouldn't call 0.3ms underperformant. But I think if you don't need the whole user record in every request then splitting the data up would be the best idea.